# How can I fill up the windows page file before physical memory?

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

There is a utility `consume.exe` that comes with [Windows Server 2003 Resource Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657) that can be used to max out CPU utilization, or fill up physical memory or disk-space, or even fill up the page-file. When run in the page-file mode, this tool does not seem to consume the physical memory first (there is no change in free-bytes)

If I were to implement a similar tool, how would I use the pagefile before using up physical memory? (Let's say I'm using C#/.net)

Comment: Disable paging altogether

Comment: Allocate virtual memory and never access it. This creates commit demand but not RAM demand.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you please elaborate on how I might go about doing that ? I found [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that I would be able to use in C++. Are there ways to allocate virtual memory in managed languages?

Comment: Call VirtualAlloc with pinvoke

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Even better: `CreateFileMapping` with `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` to allocate the mapping in the pagefile!